# Serving Files with Pyramid

Tags: python, download, pylons, paste, pyramid

I am serving quite large files from a Pyramid Application I have written.
My only problem is download managers don't want to play nice.

I can't get resume downloading or segmenting to work with download manager like DownThemAll.

```
size = os.path.getsize(Path + dFile)
response = Response(content_type='application/force-download', content_disposition='attachment; filename=' + dFile)
response.app_iter = open(Path + dFile, 'rb')
response.content_length = size
```

I think the problem may lie with `paste.httpserver` but I am not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The web server on the python side needs to support partial downloads, which happens through the [HTTP Accept-Ranges header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5). This blog post digs a bit into this matter with an example in python:

- [Python sample: Downloading file through HTTP protocol with multi-threads](http://dralu.com/?p=513)

Answer (score 8):

Pyramid 1.3 adds new response classes, [FileResponse](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.FileResponse) and [FileIter](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.FileIter) for manually serving files.

Answer (score 2):

Having been working on this problem for a while, I found

http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/file-example.html

to be a great help.